# VS Code multiple cursors under Fedora 25/Gnome 3 not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, fedora, multiline

[image]
<sub>(source: [visualstudio.com](https://code.visualstudio.com/images/editingevolved_multicursor.gif))</sub>

This is the functionality I'm missing (Shift+Alt+Down/Up) as well as the entire column selection with (Shift+Alt+MouseDragging). Only Alt+Click adds separate secondary cursors. Actually when pressing the above button combinations instead of additional cursors I get full line selection.

Not really sure why I cant get the multi-cursor working correctly so would appreciate some help.

Comment: Wayland can cause this?